# Why is reverse geocoding not working after dragging the marker once place_changed with autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am running the following, when the map starts and I move the pin, the input gets the correct new address using reverse geocoding. But if I use the input and type in an address and use the autocomplete, then I drag the marker, then the reverse geocoding won't work anymore:

```js
  var map;
  var marker;

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      draggable:true,
      title:"Drag me!"
    });

    var input = (document.getElementById('location-text-box'));

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    updateAddress();

    var latlng;
    latlng = marker.getPosition();

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
      }

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

      marker.setVisible(true);

      latlngNew = marker.getPosition();
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      updateAddress(latlngNew);

    });

    function updateAddress(latlngNew) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              $("#location-text-box").attr("value", results[1].formatted_address);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
height: 700px;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
   height: 600px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,geocode,places"></script>

<input type="text" id="location-text-box" class="form-control margin-bottom-20 query" placeholder="Your location..." required >
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what worked at the end:

```
    defaultLatLong = {
      lat: -25.363882, 
      lng: 131.044922
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: defaultLatLong,
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('location-text-box');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: defaultLatLong,
      draggable: true,
      clickable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker) {
      var latLng = marker.latLng;
      currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
      currentLongitude = latLng.lng();
      var latlng = {
        lat: currentLatitude,
        lng: currentLongitude
      };
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {
            input.value = results[0].formatted_address;
          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
      }
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      currentLatitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      currentLongitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

    });
  });
```